# [AccelStepper][PlatformIO][mbed] Request for member '' in '', which is of non-class type

Tags: class, mbed, platformio

so I have been trying to create 3 'accelstepper' objects.
[This is a screenshot of my code in case the code section doesn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6dH.png). Also, [this is a screenshot of the file "stepper_directory.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9iWi.png)

```cpp
#include <mbed.h>
#include "stepper_directory.h"

//Include accelstepper library
#include <AccelStepper.h>

//Create accelstepper object for the Z-Axis actuator
AccelStepper zaxis(uint8_t interface = AccelStepper::DRIVER, uint8_t zstep = ZSTEP, uint8_t zdir = ZDIR);

//Create accelstepper object for the theta axis actuator
AccelStepper taxis(uint8_t interface = AccelStepper::DRIVER, uint8_t tstep = TSTEP, uint8_t tdir = TDIR);

//Create accelstepper object for the magnet actuator
AccelStepper maxis(uint8_t interface = AccelStepper::DRIVER, uint8_t mstep = MSTEP, uint8_t mdir = MDIR);
```

This is the header file i've used "stepper_directory.h"

```cpp
#ifndef _STEPPER_DIRECTORY
#define  _STEPPER_DIRECTORY

#include "PinNames.h"

//Pin Definitions
#define ZSTEP   PA_7
#define ZDIR    PA_0

#define TSTEP   PA_8
#define TDIR    PA_1

#define MSTEP   PA_9
#define MDIR    PA_2
```

I've tried to setup one stepper in my main code in main.cpp as follows:

```cpp
int main() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    zaxis.setMaxSpeed(188000);

    while(1) {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    }
}
```

But the platformIO compiler is throwing out this lines:

```
src\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
src\main.cpp:17:7: error: request for member 'setMaxSpeed' in 'zaxis', which is of non-class type 'AccelStepper(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)
{aka AccelStepper(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)}'
 zaxis.setMaxSpeed(188000);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
*** [.pio\build\nucleo_f410rb\src\main.o] Error 1
```

I have been attempting to search for what is wrong with my object instantiations to no avail. I would really appreciate if there someone could explain what is wrong with this. [This is a screenshot of the error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXOxR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here.

```cpp
//Create accelstepper object for the Z-Axis actuator
AccelStepper zaxis(uint8_t interface = AccelStepper::DRIVER, uint8_t zstep = ZSTEP, uint8_t zdir = ZDIR);
```

This is a function declaration. It takes three arguments and returns `AccelStepper`. You cannot initialize an instance of `AccelStepper` with this line of code.

I assume `AccelStepper`'s constructor is something like this:

```cpp
AccelStepper AccelStepper(uint8_t interface, uint8_t zstep, uint8_t zdir);
```

You can initialize your instance this way:

```cpp
AccelStepper zaxis(AccelStepper::DRIVER, ZSTEP, ZDIR);
```

Comment: Hi Kentaro Okuda, thank you for your response. 

Just to clarify my understanding, the reason why my original line of code behaves as a function even though I intended it to be an object instantiation is because of the way I phrased my parameters?

Comment: declaration, definition and call are different. Your original code is a function declaration. It doesn't initialize an instance because you are not calling a constructor. This link may be helpful. https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/functions-in-cpp.php

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've followed your advice and it works